# MySQL - What to use procedural elements for?

Tags: mysql, database

I've got an assignment where I had to design a movie database. Among the things I am supposed to do, are procedural elements (triggers, functions and procedures for exemple). I don't have any specific tasks to perform, but rather I have to suggest ways to use these elements (and do it obvisously). And I don't find any relevant ideas to use such a feature... I've tried to find some meaningful exemples on the internet to find ideas but I didn't find anything useful...

Do you have any suggestions, tips or any exemples about how procedural elements can be used in a database? Even if it is not related to movies, I may be able to understand their usefulness and transpose this to my database.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We're glad you're here. I understand your question, thank you for asking it in such a clear manner. Unfortunately, it may not be a good fit for this site, and you will probably get some downvotes or votes to close this question as "too broad." There are guidelines for this site that some people treat very strictly — it is meant to be a place to ask about _specific_ code problems, i.e. here is a specific code sample, help me troubleshoot it. You might like to read the help center to get the best experience from this site: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.